# How to find document loader value

Tags: javascript

I want to make document loading progress bar, but I need to know the value of the document load.

If the value was `75%` then it's 75% loaded from the document.

Is there any function in JavaScript that can give me that value while loading the content of the document?

Comment: I don’t think so. I would look into something like [NProgress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress).

Comment: Actually what i want to make is literally like NProgress but is not NProgress updaing the bar in depend on some value which is the one that i am asking of it ?

Comment: I’d go with NProgress — you can’t really get this value, and NProgress will give the impression of progress when you can’t. Your users probably won’t care if the bar is accurate, as long as it’s moving.

Answer (score -1):

I could think of two approaches to achieve this as follows:

> For the following codes to work and demonstrate progression, you will need a slow generating page, you could simulate that using `sleep()` function in PHP between every portion of your page.

.

### Using javascript to set width explicitly

You could print javascript code to explicitly set the width of your loading element in different areas of the page.

**See demo:** http://jsbin.com/kovoniguqo/1/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #progress{
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      width:100px;
      height:20px;      
    }
    #progress div{
      background: green;
      width:10%;
      height:20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="progress"><div id="bar"></div></div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <script>    
    document.getElementById('bar').style.width = "20%";
  </script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <script>    
   document.getElementById('bar').style.width = "30%";
  </script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <script>    
    document.getElementById('bar').style.width = "40%";
  </script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

.

### Using document.write() and <style> tags

Although this is a non-standard approach, you could embed <style> tags inside your <body> and overwrite the css width value of your progress bar indicator.

**See demo:** http://jsbin.com/leyezixage/edit?html,output

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    #progress{
      border:1px solid #ccc;
      width:100px;
      height:20px;      
    }
    #progress div{
      background: green;
      width:10%;
      height:20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="progress"><div></div></div>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <script>    
    document.write('<style>#progress div{  width: 20%; }</style>');
  </script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <script>    
    document.write('<style>#progress div{  width: 30%; }</style>');
  </script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <script>    
    document.write('<style>#progress div{  width: 40%; }</style>');
  </script>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
</body>
</html>
```